# How to acknowledge if the message is sent successfully from the client side in a client side streaming rpc (GRPC)

Tags: go, grpc, rpc

I am having a client side rpc which sends messages to the server. The messages should be reliable and should not be lost. I am using redis pub/sub to publish the message and subscribe from it and send it using the client streaming rpc. I need to establish a protocol with acknowledgement where every message sent from the client should be acknowledged by the server and the client should retry the message if the message is not recieved by the server.

My Current Implementation

1. I converted the client stream to Bi-directional stream and send an acknowledgement message back to the client.
2. The client after sending a message, check for acknowledgement and then continue with the next message.
   This is working fine, but the down side is. I get a delay of 0.5 to 1 sec for a message. This is too much, because the message is produced at a faster rate.
   What I need is a delay of 0.1 second. Kindly help me with this. Or any other suggestion is appreciated.
   Thank you

```
func (h *Handler) SendCommandResponsesFromRedis(ctx context.Context) {
    sub := h.RedisClient.Subscribe("command_responses")
    var rccStream rcc.Agent_SendCommandResponseStreamClient
    var isFailed = false
    var ackChan = make(chan bool)

    // var err error
    for msg := range sub.Channel() {
        response := &agent.SendCommandResponseRequest{}
        err := protojson.Unmarshal([]byte(msg.Payload), response)
        if err != nil {
            h.Logger.Error("Error unmarshalling data from redis: ", err)
        }
        for {

            // Creating stream
            if rccStream == nil || isFailed {
                fmt.Println("Creating stream")
                if rccStream != nil {
                    rccStream.Context().Done()
                }
                rccStream, err = h.Client.SendCommandResponseStream(ctx)

                go func() {
                    for {

                        select {
                        case <-ctx.Done():
                            return
                        default:
                            ack, err := rccStream.Recv()
                            if err != nil {
                                h.Logger.Error("Error receiving command response stream: ", err)
                                isFailed = true
                                return
                            }

                            if ack.Status {
                                ackChan <- true
                            } else {
                                ackChan <- false
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }()

                if err != nil {
                    h.Logger.Error("Error requesting command response stream: ", err)
                    isFailed = true
                    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
                    fmt.Println("Retrying...")
                    continue
                }
                isFailed = false
            }

            // Send message in stream
            fmt.Println("Sending message in stream")
            err = rccStream.Send(&rcc.SendCommandResponseRequest{
                Response: response.Response,
            })

            // Wait for response, if status is not true wait for 5 seconds and try again by continueing the loop
            if err != nil {
                h.Logger.Error("Error sending command response stream: ", err)
                isFailed = true
                continue
            }

            if ack := <-ackChan; ack {
                break
            } else {
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
                continue
            }

        }
    }

    defer sub.Close()
}
```

Comment: I would start by profiling the code to understand exactly where is the delay. If it is in the network communication, you can try batching messages or acks (or both).